# Get value from file into decorator in other module (Python 3.10, Discord.py 2.0)

Tags: python, oop, discord, discord.py, decorator

I have a discord bot that makes use of discord.py extensions to load command cogs from other modules. I am trying to load an ID for a server/guild from my config.json file into a decorator in the extension module which is being loaded from my main module, I cannot figure out how to do this without reading the config file multiple times which wouldn't be nice.

I've written a small example of the issue.
Any help would be appreciated!

main.py (no real issue here):

```
bot = commands.Bot(prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())
with open('config.json', 'r') as f:
    config = json.load(f)

# Add this attribute so we can access the config from the cogs
bot.config = config

async def load_cogs():
    for filename in os.listdir('cogs/'):
        await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

async def main():
    await load_cogs()
    await bot.start(TOKEN)

asyncio.run(main())
```

cogs/extension.py (where the problem is):

```
class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot)
        self.bot = bot

        # The value I need from my config
        value = bot.config['value']

    @app_command.command(name='mycommand')
    @app_command.guilds()  # I need my config value passed in here
    async def command(self, interaction):
        #  do command stuff

async def setup(bot)
    await bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot))
```

Comment: you get all the files in the `cogs/` directory, but then try to load the extension from the `cog` directory

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected the typo in this post but that is not my current issue unfortunately. I wrote this as an example of the issue which is that I need to get a certain value into a decorator in cogs/extension.py without opening a file multiple times if possible.